# Get runtime error 1004 using paste method

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, paste

Description:

- I want to merge all the sheet 3 in my folder into my master workbook
- Copy the data of the merge sheet to sheet name "Step 1" to be use on calculation formula on the sheets(3)
- Copy the result values without formula from sheet3 to their origin sheet

My problem:
Using the paste special method it throws error

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

and highlight this line of codes

```
.Sheets(i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

My full code is

```
'for merge sheet from other workbooks
    Dim wbk, twb As Workbook, sPath As String, sFile As String, sName As String

    sPath = "C:\Users\mazman\Desktop\Hilmi\ data Summary\"
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Do While sFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)

        With wbk
            sName = Split(Split(.Name, "_")(6), ".")(0)
            .Sheets(3).Copy after:=twb.Sheets(twb.Sheets.Count)
            .Close 0
        End With

        With twb
        .ActiveSheet.Name = sName
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R1").RowHeight = 45
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R1").WrapText = True
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End With
        sFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set wbk = Nothing

'For copy from the merge sheet into sheet "Step 1" then copy the result in sheets(3) and paste to the origin sheet
    Dim twb As Workbook
    Set twb = ThisWorkbook

    For i = 4 To 11
    With twb
    .Sheets(i).Range("A2:R3063").Copy
    .Worksheets("STEP 1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    .Sheets(3).Range("A9:O27").Copy
    .Sheets(i).Cells.Clear 'work well until this line
    .Sheets(i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme 'start getting error on this line
    .Sheets(i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Sheets(i).Range("A1:O19").ColumnWidth = 10.8
    End With
    Next i
    Set twb = Nothing
```

I am still new in this excel vba and believe that a lot of things that I need to improve.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Untested, but try clearing first, then copying and pasting.

Comment: @BigBen what did you mean by clearing? Did you mean clearing the origin sheet? If that so I already did that using ```.Sheets(i).Cells.Clear ```

Comment: Try moving the `.Sheets(3).Range("A9:O27").Copy` to after the `.Sheets(i).Cells.Clear`.

Comment: Excel has an uncanny habit of clearing the clipboard. Use the paste command right after the copy command. as @BigBen suggested move the `.Copy` command after the `.Clear` command

Comment: @BigBen that works fine

Comment: Did you not get any conflict dimming your twb variable twice? You declared `twb` allready, no need to do it twice. Also you should try to avoid `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @JvdV those vba code is different macro so it does not conflict, By the way I already replace the ```ActiveSheet``` to their sheet index, thanks for your support